# Unity 2017.1.3f1 : CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources after Implementing Google Play services

Tags: unity-game-engine

Game is working integration seams to be success. all options are set. But for some reason during building it show me such error. 
Did anyone encounter this issue after integrating Google Play services?

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
    C:\Users\Bartosz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Bartosz/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.arch.lifecycle:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.common:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.games.bridge:com.unity.purchasing:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.android.vending.billing:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.unity3d.ads -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cardview-v7-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.cardview-v7-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-16.0.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.0.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.61\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\common\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\customtabs-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-vector-drawable-25.3.1\res" -S "D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\res"

    stderr[
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <ImageView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:scrollIndicators from <ScrollView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:36: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:24: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:59: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <ImageView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_select_dialog_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <view>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_select_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/abc_select_dialog_material for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml:32: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/notification_action for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml:37: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.taploft.idlecamp:layout/notification_action_tombstone for configuration v17.
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
    D:\Unity Project\Idle Camp 5.0\New Unity Project 1\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layou<message truncated>
```

I looked all over and couldn't find anything like that. Java HOME dir is set.

Comment: 2017.1... <thinking> there is 2018.3, try it out, maybe your google play services version is for newer unity

Comment: There should be a real error message at the end, open your editor log and find it.